# Replace entire table row using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to use JQuery to replace an entire `<tr>`. I can select the `<tr>` with no problem, I just can't figure out how to entirely replace it.

My selector/current code:

```
$("td#listprice").parents("tr:first").outerHTML(product.ListPrice)
```

This produces an error saying outerHTML is not a function.

My replacement (product.ListPrice) for the row is:

```
<tr><td>Some label</td><td>Some data</td></tr>
```

I don't exactly know that `.outerHTML` is what I'm wanting to use, I just know that I want to replace the entire table row including the `<tr>` and closing `</tr>`. I've seen some examples of replace a table row but they look way more complex than they need to be. I don't think I should have to remove the row in order to replace it, should I?

Comment: "but they look way more complex than they need to be" - but they worked. And your simple one - doesn't. ;-)

Comment: `outerHTML` should be `.html(product.ListPrice)`

Comment: Zerkms, we'll see. I bet someone posts a 'simple' way of doing it. Thank you for your answer. (Or was it an answer?)

Comment: Thank you Sheikh. I figured it didn't need to be 20 lines of code to get it done. I'l try this!

Comment: @SheikhHeera. `outerHTML` isn't `html()`. The later is `innerHTML`.

Comment: In jQuery `innerHTML` is `html()`, am I wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)?

```
$("#listprice").parent().replaceWith(product.ListPrice);
```

And yes, you can better use `parent` or `closest` instead of `parents` (see comments below).

Comment: Better use `parent()`. A `td` element can only be inside a `tr` element. No need to make it overly complicated.

Comment: What about `$("td#listprice").closest('tr')`

Comment: @SheikhHeera. Read the comment above.

Comment: For some reason it's not changing the table row. `.replaceWith` seems like a good way of doing it, but it has no effect either. I know for sure that `product.ListPrice` is valid - I can see that in firebug. Here is my current line of code: `$("td#listprice").parent().replaceWith(product.ListPrice);`.

Comment: For some reason none of these are working... I'm assuming these would also replace the innerhtml as well? I'm not getting any errors either. Like I said above, I know product.ListPrice is correct because I can copy/paste it in another html and see the results. My current line of code is: `$("td#listprice").parent().html(product.ListPrice);`. It looks correct to me. :S

Comment: I think I know why this isn't working. Your solutions are correct, but I have a different issue. When the page is initially rendered, my `<tr>` et al is all being displayed as text on the page. It's not being rendered correctly and I believe this is because I'm using `&lt;` and `&gt;` as well as `&quot;` when I create these strings in my XSLT stylesheet. I'm not sure why this is having an effect. Might need to post another question. In my html page source all of these tags show up as `&lt;`, etc. So, the selector isn't locating my desired row/column.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 ways to do this:

```
replaceText = "<tr><td>Some label3</td><td>Some data3</td></tr>"
  $("td#listprice").parent().html(replaceText)
 //OR    $("td#listprice").parents("tr:first").html(replaceText)
```

​

Comment: I think your suggestion is pretty much like the one from gdoron above. For some reason it's not working. Am going to continue playing with it, but I'm stumped! The code looks right and there are no errors.